# How do I get into Canada?

Tags: south-park-the-fractured-but-whole

So I'm walking up the road into Canada and I came across a huge wall. They built a wall on their border!

A very nice Canadian is telling me all aboot how awesome life is in Canada and how things are going great. I'd love to get in there!

Is there any way to convince this guy to let me in or is there a way around the wall?

Comment: Maybe try asking [Travel StackExchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com)? :P

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGTznIy6i4w is highly relevant.

Comment: Did they make America pay for it? That would be an akward case of irony.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nope, there is no way in.

It's just a reference to [*Where My Country Gone?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_My_Country_Gone%3F) (Episode 2 Season 19) of the show, where Canada built a wall to keep Americans out.

Comment: They are really sorey.

Comment: If you click on it enough I believe that they reference DLC. Whether or not that’s a joke is up to interpretation.

Comment: It may also be referencing The Stick of Truth where you could visit Canada as a retro 8-bit RPG.

Comment: @Steven That was what I was thinking as well.  Canada was a pretty memorable part of the original game.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: Yes that too.  If you pick up the member berries found just before that screen, they say _"Ooo, 'member when Canada was like an old school RPG?  Ooo, I 'member!"_

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson: I'm going to go with intentional joke. The bus stop (just next to the South Park sign) is from the DLC busline, and the people waiting there are complaining that they've been waiting for over a year. Seems like another jab at those who "pathologically" want more DLC.